# Changing Background Image on Aside with internal/external CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a class homework assignment involving nodes and nodelists that I thought would be simple, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to change this one part.

I have been given an HTML, js, and css file along with some images. The goal is to change the background image in the  tag by using a DOM method but NOT getElementByID. I am thinking to use querySelector, but can't figure out how to go between these internal and external style sheets. Here's the code:

HTML (with internal CSS)

```
<html>
<style> 
   #bkgImage {
       background-image: url(images/bg2.jpg);
   }
</style>

<body>

<aside>
        Some text goes here<br />
        <button id="button">Change background image</button> 
</aside>

</html>
```

CSS (external)

```
aside 
{
    background-image: url(../images/bg1.jpg)
}
```

JS

```
var clickHandler = function()
{

}

objButton.onclick = clickHandler;
```

I'm thinking something like

```
var changeBackground = document.querySelector('bkgImage');
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here.

The aside loads bg1.jpg (which is in an external stylesheet) but when I click the button, I need it to change to bg2.jpg which is in an internal stylesheet. This is what is throwing me off the most I think.

Need to add some Javascript into that clickHandler function, but not exactly sure what all I need.

I'd appreciate any guidance on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your homework for you :)

https://jsfiddle.net/x2241vrq/

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var aside = document.getElementsByTagName('aside');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    aside[0].id = 'bkgImage';
});
```

Some notes.

1. You forgot to close out your `<aside>` tag. So I took care of that for you.
2. I changed from background images to colors since I didn't have your images. But switch the CSS and it'll work fine.

Comment: this works, but for some reason, not until the 2nd click. I think this may be because I've already got a button variable declared outside of the function. So basically var objButton = document.getElementById("button);

I tried switching things around in your code to adapt to mine but couldn't get it to work. Could you please help a little more? Thanks!

Comment: since I already have a objButton.onclick = clickHandler; to run the function, I think putting the eventListener for a click is causing me to have to do two clicks. How would you write that code knowing that the buttonclick is already being handled somewhere else. So just the base code for switching the background images. Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I got it, I just stripped the code down to the aside ariab and the aside[0].id . Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sorry I wasn't around to help with that! Glad you got it though. My personal preference is to never have click handlers in the HTML. I always do them in JS. Keeps the HTML cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You can just toggle the class of the aside to use a different background. I wouldn't alter the id with javascript or use the id for the background toggle styling... thats messy. Here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/7na9xndk/1/

html

```
<aside class="bg1"><button id="button">change image</button></aside>
```

css

```
.bg1{
    background:red;
}
.bg2{
    background:lime;
}
```

js

```
var button = document.querySelector("#button");
var aside = document.getElementsByTagName("aside")[0];
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    aside.classList.toggle("bg1");
    aside.classList.toggle("bg2");
})
```

Notice that I am using an event listener rather than a straight event handler.

Comment: This works great, thanks, but it does go against the rules of the assignment which are requiring me to add something into the class, not toggle it. Thanks for the help though!